# NullInjectorError: No providers for NgbAlertConfig in prod mode using aot

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, ng-bootstrap, aot

our project has a toaster component which uses NgbAlert. This toaster component is imported from a propriety common UI components package which is then imported in the **jhipster** generated angular web app.

**The Issue**

The application works totally fine in the development build (yarn start) but in the prod mode (yarn build) the application generates an error stating **'NullInjectorError: No providers for NgbAlertConfig'**. (A stack trace has been attached).

[image]

This error was initially experienced for the **NgbModal** and **NgbDropdown** which was fixed by adding them into the providers array of the component which uses them.

**inside the propriety package**

toaster.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'toaster',
templateUrl: './toaster.component.html',
styleUrls: [
    './toaster.component.scss'
],
providers: [NgbAlert, NgbAlertConfig],
animations: [
    toasterAnimation
]
})

export class ToasterComponent implements OnInit {
// An array of toasts to store toaster objects
public toasts: Toaster[];
// A map of toast and its timeout ids
public timeOutIds: Map<number, number> = new Map<number, number>();
// Auto increment incremnet of toaster id;
public toastId: number;


constructor(
    private toasterService: ToasterService,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private alertConfig: NgbAlertConfig
) {
    this.toastId = 0;
    this.toasts = [];
}
```

toaster.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let toast of toasts" @toasterState>
    <ngb-alert [type]="toast.type" [dismissible]="true" (close)="dismissToast(toast)">
        <strong class="alert-heading">{{toast.title | titlecase }}</strong>
        <div>{{toast.message}}</div>
    </ngb-alert>
</div>
```

toaster.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbAlertModule.forRoot()
],
declarations: [
    ToasterComponent
],
exports: [
    ToasterComponent
],
entryComponents: [
]
})
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ToasterModule.forRoot(),
    ComponentsModule.forRoot(),
    NavbarModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeModule,
    EntityModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
],
```

Answer (score 3):

import NgbAlertConfig into your **parent module** instead of toaster component

Comment: Thanks @Omkar, it is assumed to be added in the providers array of the parent module. Hence, it was added to the module where NgbAlert is used (i.e. ToasterModule) which didn't work and then we did try adding it to the AppModule and even that was not helpful.